# Executing a command in bash, passed as string, with proper file wildcard operation

Tags: command-line, bash, c++

I mean to execute a `bash` command, passed explicitly as a string to `bash`, which can handle properly file wildcard and variable expansion operations.

I tried the sample command (see below for what I actually need, which is more "demanding"):

```
$ bash -c "files=* ; echo ${files} ; for file in {0..2} ; do echo ${file} ; done"
```

and I get 4 blank lines (one from `echo ${files}` and three from `for file in {0..2} ...`).
Actually, this will echo whatever the variables `files` and `file` contain in the calling environment, instead of evaluating inside.

What I need is actually a combination of things to work:

1. Evaluate properly `files=*` within the running environment and directory (it would actually be a different pattern, but this is irrelevant).
2. Loop properly over `${files}`, with `for file in ${files}` (instead of `for file in {0..2}`).
3. Use string substitution with `do mv $file ${file/-0003/-0002}` (instead of `do echo ${file}`).
   This, combined with the need for calling from C++ with `system`, is what forces me to prepend the command with `bash`, as with `system("bash -c ...");`. If I do not prepend it, the default shell `dash` is used, which does not support string substitution, giving me the error `sh: 1: Bad substitution`.

This question is specific.

In addition, any other alternative that allows me to make a system call from C++, and perform: 1) file wildcard use, 2) string substitution, 3) proper looping, would be ok.

Comment: Boost may be an option. I would rather not use additional dependencies, but there it is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array, and appropriate quoting. For example, given:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file4  file5  file6
```

then

```
$ bash -c 'files=(*) ; echo "${files[@]}" ; for file in "${files[@]}" ; do echo "${file/2/3}" ; done'
file1 file2 file4 file5 file6
file1
file3
file4
file5
file6
```

Comment: This essentially worked very well. Now I only need to detect the case where `files=(*)` is not actually matching anything, but keeping the file pattern in the variable value, so I do not enter the subsequent loop.

Comment: @sancho.s use `shopt -s nullglob` so that `*` expands to nothing if nothing matches

Answer (score 1):

With double quotes, the variables will be expanded in the calling shell. Use single quotes:

```
$ cd /; bash -c 'files=* ; echo ${files} ; for file in {0..2} ; do echo ${file} ; done'
bin boot dev etc home lib lib64 lost+found mnt opt proc root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var
0
1
2
```

You should actually use arrays, but:

You should actually [`fork`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/fork.2.html) and [`exec`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/exec.3.html), if you want to call a specific command with specific arguments:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main()
{
    pid_t child = fork();
    if (child == -1) // fork failed
        std::perror("fork");
    else if (child == 0) // child
        execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-c", "files=* ; echo ${files} ; for file in {0..2} ; do echo ${file} ; done", NULL);
    else // parent
        wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: The command you wrote, without double quotes and arrays (as in the answer by steeldriver) also worked well in my case. I will check the next point now.